# cannot delete records from a table which has one to many Mapping with another

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

In my spring boot application, employee and project are two entity classes, here project has a one to many relation with employee. Here I'm expecting all my employees associated with a project in employee table to get deleted when i call an api which deletes project in project table.

Here is my entity classes, this is project class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class ProjectEmp  {

@Id
private int proId;
private String proname;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Employee.class,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name="eproId",referencedColumnName = "proId")
private List<Employee> emplo= new ArrayList<Employee>();
public List<Employee> getEmplo() {
    return emplo;
}
public void setEmplo(List<Employee> emplo) {
    this.emplo = emplo;
}
...............
```

This is My employee class, it is also having many to one relation with another class called department:

```
public class Employee  {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int empId;
private String empName;
private String desig;
private int eproId; 
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Department.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="empdep",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "empId"), inverseJoinColumns =@JoinColumn(name="depId"))
@JsonManagedReference
@JsonIgnore
private Department dep;
public Department getDep() {
    return dep;
}
public void setDep(Department dep) {
    this.dep = dep;
}
public int geteproId() {
    return eproId;
}
public  Employee seteproId(int eproId) {
    this.eproId = eproId;
    return this;
}
public String getDesig() {
    return desig;
}
public Employee setDesig(String desig) {
    this.desig = desig;
    return this;
}

...............
```

This is my controller to pass the project id that has to be deleted:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deluse(@PathVariable int id) throws Exception
{
     empService.delpro(id);
}
```

this is my service to delete the record:

```
public void delpro(int id) {
    ProjectEmp pp= proRepo.findByproId(id);
    pp.getEmplo();  
    proRepo.delete(pp);
    }
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
  Column 'epro_id' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1340) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
```

The expected output is to get the project id and employee id related to it to be deleted.

Comment: do you have foreign key relationships between table as well?

Comment: just the one that is in my code in project class ...nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, the solution is to set the foriegn key updatable = false . Thanks for the help ,hope it is useful to some one else.

Answer (score 0):

Add ON DELETE CASCADE  in your Project Table foreign key which is referencing employee table primary key.

it will work like whenever you delete any project it will CASCADE delete operation to it's foreign key i.e. employee table also.

For more details how to do it, you can visit http://mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: CascadeType.remove  does the same

Answer (score 0):

This is happened when we have **duplicate indexes**. So we have to index the variables accurately in the Database class.

Comment: Please add some fragment to support your proposed solution.